# Cannot read property 'admin' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this problem in the time i am in admin routes and i try to add a new article or a new image in my database , the same things happen even when i want to update something ....
this is  my codes ?

```
exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.isAuthenticated() && res.locals.user.admin == 1) {
        next();
    } else {
        req.flash("danger", "please log in as admin");
        res.redirect("/users/login");
    }
}

var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var User = require("../models/user");
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");


module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {

        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "No user found" });
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) console.log(err);

                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Wrong password" });
                }
            })
        });

    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

Anyone one can help the problem is i think in res.locals.user.admin but in other admin routes works ok but only when i want to add a new and edit a think happen this problem

Comment: `console.log(res.locals)` Apparently there would be no `user` property, so work out where that should be set and why it is not there when you're looking for it. Presumably there is some middle-ware involved which you are expecting to set this. Guessing it's more likely `req.locals` anyway.

Comment: the problem is only in the router.post , i have use the middleware there and res.locals in this routes are null , i deleted middlewares from post routes and now is fine but how i can i make the post routes with middlewares so only the admin can make new ?